# Name Services under started process in cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, service, svchost

In windows 10 cmd, I started a process `C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k RPCSS -p` successfully. How do I list the services it is currently managing?

I've looked at `tasklist`, however, that requires the image name, and I am unsure how to identify which `svchost` it is, in process explorer.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you develop a new service? Do you maybe need a scheduled task?

Comment: @An-dir No, I'm trying to see which services the process is currently managing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic) in cmd to get the commandline of the process :

---

```
wmic process where "name like 'svchost.exe' And CommandLine!=Null" get commandline /Value
```